# Box2D - Firing bullet from rotating gun

Tags: c++, visual-studio, box2d

i have a little trouble as title said: i can't figure out how to shoot the bullet toward the direction the gun is pointing at.

[image: Picture of problem]

Here's short version code, for my bullet firing:

```
b2BodyDef bd;
bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bd.bullet = true;
bd.position = gun->GetPosition();//bullet start at the middle of the gun
m_bullet = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
m_bullet->CreateFixture(&fd);           
m_bullet->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter( ??? ,true);
```

At first i thought first param is the direction you want the body go toward so i put in `gun->GetWorldPoint(b2Vec2(0.0f,-5.0f))` (middle of the gun's muzzle). Big miss! After a while i thought i should try put in the vector of current gun's rotation degrees `b2Vec2 vect = b2Vec2(cos(angle * PI/180), sin(angle * PI/180));` but then the bullet won't fly at all. Now i am all out of ideas. Please, some light.

Full version of code:

```
public:
b2Body* m_bullet = NULL;
b2Body* gun;
b2RevoluteJoint* joint1;
b2FixtureDef fd;

TestingStuff()
{
    {
        //body
        b2CircleShape circle1;
        circle1.m_radius = 1.6f;

        fd.shape = &circle1;
        fd.density = 1.0f;
        fd.filter.groupIndex = -1;          

        b2BodyDef bd1;
        bd1.type = b2_staticBody;
        bd1.position.Set(-5.0f, 9.0f);
        b2Body* body1 = m_world->CreateBody(&bd1);
        body1->CreateFixture(&fd);

        //gun
        b2PolygonShape box;
        box.SetAsBox(0.5f, 5.0f);

        fd.shape = &box;
        fd.density = 1.0f;
        fd.filter.groupIndex = -1;

        b2BodyDef bd2;
        bd2.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bd2.position.Set(-5.0f, 8.0f);
        gun = m_world->CreateBody(&bd2);
        gun->CreateFixture(&fd);

        //joint
        b2RevoluteJointDef jd1;
        jd1.Initialize(gun, body1, bd1.position);
        jd1.enableMotor = true;
        jd1.maxMotorTorque = 90;
        jd1.motorSpeed = 180 * DEGTORAD;//DEGTORAD=0.0174532925199432957f
        joint1 = (b2RevoluteJoint*) m_world->CreateJoint(&jd1);
    }

}

void Keyboard(int key)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_COMMA:
        if (m_bullet != NULL)
        {
            m_world->DestroyBody(m_bullet);
            m_bullet = NULL;
        }

        {
            //bullet
            b2CircleShape shape;
            shape.m_radius = 0.25f;

            fd.shape = &shape;
            fd.density = 1;
            fd.restitution = 0.05f;
            fd.filter.groupIndex = -1;

            b2BodyDef bd;
            bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            bd.bullet = true;
            bd.position = gun->GetPosition();
            m_bullet = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
            m_bullet->CreateFixture(&fd); 
            m_bullet->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter( ??? ,true);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "`b2Vec2(cos(angle * PI/180), sin(angle))`", is `angle` in radians or not?

Comment: @genpfault: for 90 degrees, i will put the angle = 90.0f

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to point out that didn't you convert `sin()`'s argument to radians, only `cos()`'s.  You need to do both or else the results will be meaningless, or at least a one-way ticket to Funkytown.

Comment: @genpfault: thanks for pointing out. Me and my sleepy head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good sleep i found the solution after few more trial and error.

```
//bullet
float degAngle = joint1->GetJointAngle() * RADTODEG + 180;
b2Vec2 vect = b2Vec2(sin(degAngle* (b2_pi / 180)) * 10, cos(degAngle* (b2_pi / 180)) * 10);
m_bullet->ApplyLinearImpulseToCenter(vect ,true);
```

The * 10 is to increase the impulse, make the bullet fly faster and farther, for the sake of testing i just make it 10. Notice that this code is just for testing, if you want to make it more realistic, increase the impulse as well as make the bullet go toward the muzzle instead of go toward the vector it had been fired at.